# Changing video source HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, video, coffeescript

SO I have the following html code.

```
<div class="panel">
        <div class="col-sm-9">>
            <video id="currentVideo" width="650" height="350" controls>
              <source src="{{currentVideo.Source}}" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" ng-click="showVideo(video)">
            <ul ng-repeat="video in videoHelpFiles" id="playlist">
                <div ng-click="showVideo(video)">
                    <span><h4> {{video.Title}} </h4></span>
                    <span><p> {{video.Description}} </p></span>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my coffee script.

```
.controller 'HelpCtrl', (
    $scope

) ->
    $scope.videoHelpFiles = [
            Title: "Video 1"
            Description: "Desc 1"
            Source: '../../videos/video1.mp4'
        ,
            Title: "Video 2"
            Description: "Desc 2"
            Source: '../../videos/video2.mp4'
        ]

    $scope.currentVideo = $scope.videoHelpFiles[0]

    $scope.showVideo = (video) ->
        $scope.currentVideo = video
```

My question is how do I get the video to change on click. This code works when I use an iFrame instead of video which obviously I don't want to do but can anyone explain why this doesn't work when I try to use video tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar problem... try this way:

```
<video id="currentVideo" src="{{currentVideo.Source}}" width="650" height="350" controls>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I actually can't thank you enough that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your showVideo(video)

```
   <div class="col-sm-3" ng-click="showVideo(video)">
```

**video** instance not in the scope of ng-repeat. I will send undefined reference to showVideo function

Comment: Oh ok thanks didn't notice that. Have you any ideas though of why when I use <video> instead of an iframe it brakes the code?

Comment: did you try ng-src ?

Comment: Ya I did, doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126005/angularjs-ng-repeat-img-ang-video

follow this link